# how do i access a specific element in js?

Tags: javascript, php, dataset

I want to display a menu for that clicked element when I click on a certain element.

[image]
[image]

to make it look like on screenshots. In the future, by clicking on the "edit" or "delete" span, it will edit or delete the data of the field selected by the user.

```
<?php
$checkProducts = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `products`");
while ($resCheckProduct = mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkProducts)) {
    $checkUnits = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `units` WHERE id_unit = {$resCheckProduct['unit']}");
    while ($resCheckUnits = mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkUnits)) {
?>

        <tr class="tr-content">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""></td>
            <td><span class="icon-menu-span" data-id="<?= $resCheckProduct['id_product'] ?>"></span>
                <div class="table-div-menu-product" data-id="<?= $resCheckProduct['id_product'] ?>">
                    <span>edit</span>
                    <span>delete</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><?= $resCheckProduct['name'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $resCheckProduct['description'] ?></td>
            <td><img class="tableProduct-img" src="<?= $resCheckProduct['image'] ?>" alt=""></td>
            <td><?= $resCheckProduct['available_balance'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $resCheckUnits['abbreviated'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $resCheckProduct['retail_price'] ?>₽</td>
            <td><?= $resCheckProduct['purchase_price'] ?>₽</td>
            <td><?= $resCheckProduct['date_of_creation'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $resCheckProduct['date_of_change'] ?></td>
        </tr>

<?php
    }
}
?>
```

```
var
    butOpenWindowMenu = document.getElementsByClassName('icon-menu-span')[butOpenWindowMenu.dataset.id],
    modalWindowMenu = document.getElementsByClassName('table-div-menu-product')[modalWindowMenu.dataset.id];

butOpenWindowMenu.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modalWindowMenu.style.display = 'block';
});

window.addEventListener('click', function (modal) {
    if (modal.target == modalWindowMenu) {
        modalWindowMenu.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Comment: How can you use `butOpenWindowMenu.dataset.id` in the initialization of `butOpenWindowMenu`?

Comment: You should loop over all the `.icon-menu-span` elements, adding the event listener to each of them (or use event delegation). Then the listener can use `e.target` to get the one that you clicked on, and `e.target.dataset.id` to get its ID.

Comment: send documentation please

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelector` and pass the css selector `document.querySelector('icon-menu-span[data-id=*]')`

you can also grab the data-id from the clicked target and use that inside the css selector to open that element or use relative dom navigation to update the menu item.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this to open them:

```
var butOpenWindowMenus = document.querySelectorAll('.icon-menu-span');

for (var butOpenWindowMenu of butOpenWindowMenus) {
  butOpenWindowMenu.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.table-div-menu-product[data-id="'+this.dataset.id+'"]).style.display = 'block';
  })
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).